# Send FCM notifications from PHP asynchronously

Tags: php, asynchronous, nginx, slim, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building my mobile app's API using PHP and I need to send Firebase push notifications to the users when some requests arrive.

However, when I call my notification sending function, my code blocks and the client does not get a response from the server until the `sendNotificaiton` function returns, wich may take up to 9 seconds depending on when Firebase responds.

Is there a way to run that function asynchronously? I am using Slim Framework 3, so echoing the response before running the `sendNotification` function is not an option, since I'm using `return $response->withJson($data)` at the end of my route.

The app seems very laggy since the user is waiting for a notification to be sent, even though that's the server's business, so sending a response back to the user before attempting to send the notification to the other user seems like the way to go. Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S.: I'm using a Nginx server with PHP 7.0

Comment: Given the parameters in the description - no, there isn't, as PHP doesn't expose any sort of interface for dealing with asynchronous tasks unless you create a CLI script which uses event notification interface. Library that could help you achieve this is [Icicle](https://icicle.io/). Since you're using `php-fpm` behind nginx and you use `return` to return an object, it seems you can't even "hang up" using `fastcgi_finish_request();` function. An option could be to use a queue that you fill up, send response to the user and then queue "speaks" to firebase in background.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm looking into Gearman right now and I think I'll go with that. Any other queue library suggestions?

Comment: I think that Gearman is the only out of the box solution. You could probably achieve wonders with ZeroMQ and Icicle but it'd be a lot of work really for the same thing you'll achieve with Gearman.

Comment: Yup, you were right. Got everything up and running with Gearman and Supervisor. Everything seems to be working fine, let's hope it will perform as well under load :) Thank you!

Comment: Well you've done everything on your own, it's refreshing to see people solving their problems successfully, I'm glad you got it working! Good luck! :)